# react native redux: how do I update a specific value in a slice

Tags: react-native, redux

Here's my redux configuration:

**userSlice.js**

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    avatar: "",
    id: "",
};


export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUser: (state, action) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                name: action.payload.name,
                email: action.payload.email,
                avatar: action.payload.avatar,
                id: action.payload.id,
            };
        },
    },
});

export const { setUser, logout } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userSlice from "./slices/userSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userSlice,
    },
});
```

**app.js**

```js
<Provider store={store}>
    <Stack.Navigator >
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Signin" component={Signin} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</Provider>
```

Here's some conext:

1. I Log in then put values into the user slice through the response of the fetch

```js
const newUser = {
    name: oj.name,
    email: oj.email,
    avatar: oj.avatar,
    id: oj.sub,
};
dispatch(setUser(newUser));
```

2. After Logging in, I console.log these values this way:

```js
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
console.log(user)
```

And this is what it shows:

```js
Object {
      "avatar": "url",
      "email": "asd",
      "id": "61bcf738e954f7ffc11d507d",
      "name": "Asd",
}
```

I want to update `name` from `"name": "Asd"` to `"name": "bill"` without changing the others and this is my try:

```js
const newUser = {                 
 name: "bill"
};
dispatch(setUser(newUser));
```

It works, but then the other propeties(email, avatar, id) become undefined. So how can I update a single value without touching the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the spread operator to merge the existing state with your new payload.

Currently, you overwrite the `name`, `email`, `avatar`, and `id` properties:

```js
return {
    ...state,
    name: action.payload.name,
    email: action.payload.email,
    avatar: action.payload.avatar,
    id: action.payload.id,
};
```

This will merge only the included properties:

```js
return {
    ...state,
    ...action.payload,
};
```